# Add limit and offset to query that was created from a String

Tags: java, jooq

I have query as String like

```
select name from employee
```

and want to limit the number of rows with limit and offset.

Is this possible with jOOQ and how do I do that?

Something like:

```
dsl.fetch("select name from employee").limit(10).offset(10);
```

Comment: From the official doc: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/limit-clause/

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: No it's simply not possible. Because the return type of the method fetch has no limit or offset

Comment: I don't know Jooq too well, but aren't you loosing the rdbms independence by using a string query? If that is the case, I think you need to resort to the offset/limit syntax of your particular database.

Comment: It's an exception that I use jOOQ that way. It's simply because we have SQL statements stored in the database that must be executed and I want to limit the number of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you're close, but you cannot use `fetch(sql)`, because that eagerly executes the query and it will be too late to append `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. I generally don't recommend the approach offered by [Sergei Petunin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59576833/521799), because that way, you will tell the RDBMS less information about what you're going to do. The execution plan and resource allocations are likely going to be better if you actually use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

There are two ways to do what you want to achieve:

#### Use the parser

You can use [`DSLContext.parser()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#parser()) to parse your SQL query and then modify the resulting `SelectQuery`, or create a derived table from that. Creating a derived table is probably a bit cleaner:

```
dsl.selectFrom(dsl.parser().parse("select name from employee"))
   .limit(10)
   .offset(10)
   .fetch();
```

The drawback is that the parser will have to understand your SQL string. Some vendor specific features will no longer be available.

The advantage (starting from jOOQ 3.13) is that you will be able to provide your generated code with attached converters and data type bindings this way, as jOOQ will "know" what the columns are.

#### Use plain SQL

You were already using plain SQL, but the wrong way. Instead of fetching the data eagerly, just wrap your query in [`DSL.table()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table(java.lang.String)) and then use the same approach as above.

When using plain SQL, you will have to make sure manually, that the resulting SQL is syntactically correct. This includes wrapping your query in parentheses, and possibly aliasing it, depending on the dialect you're using:

```
dsl.selectFrom(table("(select name from employee)").as("t"))
   .limit(10)
   .offset(10)
   .fetch();
```

Comment: I knew there must be a jOOQ solution  thank you and happy new year

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do with a string query is to create a `ResultQuery` from it. It allows you to limit the maximum amount of rows fetched by the underlying `java.sql.Statement`:

```
create.resultQuery("select name from employee").maxRows(10).fetch();
```

or to fetch lazily and then scroll through the cursor:

```
create.resultQuery("select name from employee").fetchLazy().fetch(10);
```

Adding an offset or a limit to a query is only possible using a `SelectQuery`, but I don't think there's any way to transform a string query to a `SelectQuery` in JOOQ.

Actually, if you store SQL queries as strings in the database, then you are already in a non-typesafe area, and might as well append `OFFSET x LIMIT y` directly to a string-based query. Depending on the complexity of your queries, it might work.

Comment: Thank you that helped. I decided to append offset and limit as strings.

Comment: *"to fetch lazily and then scroll through the cursor"* - Make sure to put your cursor in a `try-with-resources` statement to prevent resource leaks. *"but I don't think there's any way to transform a string query to a SelectQuery in JOOQ."* - You can always use [`DSLContext.parser()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#parser()).